How do I get a particular array element's value whose position keeps changing using NiFi JsonPath
How do I get a particular array element's value whose position keeps changing using NiFi JsonPath
Input JSON:
{
"phones": [
    {
      "type": "H",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "number": "1113802141",
      "operation": "INSERT"
    },
    {
      "type": "M",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "number": "2225336782",
      "operation": "INSERT"
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "number": "3337274003",
      "operation": "INSERT"
    }
}

I'm trying to get the value of "operation" of the array element that has type='M'.
$.phones[?(@.type=='M')].operation -> THIS DOESN'T WORK in NiFi Evaluate Json path.
Can you suggest how else I can solve this? the position of array element "type": "M" keeps changing for different operations.

To get the "operation" value where type='M' from your JSON in NiFi, use a QueryRecord processor with this query:
SELECT $.phones[?(@.type=='M')].operation AS operation

This will create a new flow file attribute named "operation" with the desired value.
